# Should my AngularJS app use one main module, or multiple?

Tags: angularjs, grails

I am attempting to add AngularJS to a Grails application that I'm working on.

Specifically I am adding Angular functionality to one part of my site, for example to all the pages for Users.

I started off creating a Users module which I was adding controllers and services to. Then I hit a point where I needed some basic configuration code that I know I'm going to want in other areas of my site - transforming http parameters so that my backend can understand them (http://victorblog.com/2012/12/20/make-angularjs-http-service-behave-like-jquery-ajax/).

This leads me to believe that I need a base module for my entire application. However, I'm still very new to Angular and I don't understand how my Users module will inherit this configuration from a base module. Is that even possible? Or should I just have 1 base module that I add every controller and service for my entire app to?

edit: After some testing it looks like if I define a module and then give it as a dependency of another:

```
var moduleB = angular.module('ModuleB', ["ModuleA"])
```

My configuration from ModuleA will be respected within ModuleB. This doesn't make any sense to me though, what if I list two dependencies with conflicting configurations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We resolve this problem like this:

1. Create 'Core' module which consist all base functionality (for example: 'baseHttp', some utils factory, template cache factory and other base services).
2. Create specific modules. Example:

   `var task = angular.module('task', ["core"]);`

Then if it need we inject base service (like utils factory) to 'task' controllers or services and just use it. But some times we need to inherit from base service and add/override methods. For this purpose we use klass.js (you may use any other inherit library). For example:

At 'core' module

```
(function (module) {
  module.factory("baseHttp", baseHttp);

  baseHttp.$inject = ['baseRest'];
  function baseHttp(baseRest) {

      var api = {             
          createItem: function (item) {
              return this.post("create", item);
          },           

          // ... other methods  

      };

      return baseRest.extend(api);
  };     

})(angular.module("core"));
```

'baseRest' is decorator for angular '$http'.

At 'task' module:

```
(function (module) {
  module.factory("baseHttp", taskHttp);

  taskHttp.$inject = ['baseHttp'];
  function taskHttp(baseHttp) {

      var api = {  
          // override base method          
          createItem: function (item) {
              return this.post("createTask", item);
          },           

          // add new method
          read: function (id) {
              return this.get("readTask", id);
          }, 

          // ... other methods  

      };

      return baseHttp.extend(api);
  };     

})(angular.module("task"));
```

As a result we can inherit some services from core or can just use core services in code.

Answer (score 1):

Angular will complain if directives from two different modules try to create scope on the same element. This may be more likely to happen if you have different directives with the same names.

To reduce the likelihood for directive collisions, you should define your directives in a module with a unique namespace (ng is taken).

I recommend that you have one ng-app with dependencies.